# Recyclerview item click ripple effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add `Ripple` Effect to `RecyclerView`'s item. I had a look online, but could not find what I need.  I have tried `android:background` attribute to the `RecyclerView` itself and set it to `"?android:selectableItemBackground"` but it did not work.:

My Parent layout is like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dailyTaskList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and adapter template is shown in below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                style="@style/kaho_panel_sub_heading_textview_style"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                style="@style/kaho_content_small_textview_style"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Kindly give me solution

Comment: To which parent you tried `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Adding the `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` to the top most parent of your item layout should do the trick. 
However in some cases it still misses the animation, adding the `android:clickable="true"` does it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            style="@style/kaho_panel_sub_heading_textview_style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            style="@style/kaho_content_small_textview_style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For `ConstraintLayout` doesn't work.

Comment: It works with ConstraintLayout (try to set clickable and focusable to true).

Comment: Adding the android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" to the top most parent of my item layout worked.

Comment: 3 years later and this is the only answer that works out of the many on SO

Comment: Use it every day ;)

Answer (score 3):

In your recyclerView Item Parent, Add

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                style="@style/kaho_panel_sub_heading_textview_style"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                style="@style/kaho_content_small_textview_style"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```