# how I can add a ripple inside a recyclerview?

Tags: android, ripple

how I can add ripple like this vedio

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rr3UAafPOZ0

if there lists ripple please give me url

Comment: ok but how I can change color ripple??

Comment: Create a `RippleDrawable` put it inside `drawable-v21` . Search for it . Have a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47857979/4168607).

Comment: can set example

Answer (score 0):

[I've already answered to a similar question, you check the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523680/recyclerview-item-click-ripple-effect/38524089#38524089)

---

Which basically consists of adding the following to your item's layout:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: If it's a similar question, why not flag this question as a duplicate?

Comment: I want like video and change color

Comment: Michael Dood It was flagged.

haley - check the ADM's comment on your question. Also you should be more specific on your questions also search first.

Comment: I dont know why all give me -5 why I'm banned now

Comment: Because this is a duplicate if you search SO you'll find the answer that you need. Don't be lazy :)